# Left/Right join in oneToMany relation EF core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have the following situation: I have a class `UsuarioExterno` which contains a navigation property `List<InscripcionRegistroCurso> Inscripciones`

Each `InscripcionRegistroCurso` class contains a reference to `UsuarioExterno`

```
public class UsuarioExterno : Persona
{
        public int UsuarioExternoId { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Localidad")]
        public Localidad Localidad { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Organismo")]
        public string Organismo { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Sector")]
        public List<InscripcionRegistroCurso> Inscripciones { get; set; }
        public bool SectorPrivado { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Ocupación")]
        public string Ocupacion { get; set; }

        public UsuarioExterno() : base()
        {
        }
}

public class InscripcionRegistroCurso
{
        public int InscripcionRegistroCursoId { get; set; }
        public Calificacion Calificacion { get; set; }
        public List<Asistencia> Asistencias { get; set; }
        public UsuarioExterno UsuarioExterno { get; set; }
        public Curso Curso { get; set; }
}

public class Curso
{
        public int CursoId { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }
}
```

This is my linq query

```
public async Task<List<UsuarioAgenteInscripto>> GetAllUsuariosExternosWithInscripcionToCourseId(int? CourseId)
{
    var query = from u in _context.UsuariosExternos
                join i in _context.InscripcionesRegistrosCursos
                          on u.UsuarioExternoId equals i.UsuarioExterno.UsuarioExternoId
                into inscripcionRegistro
                from inscripcion in inscripcionRegistro.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new UsuarioAgenteInscripto
                        {
                            Nombre = u.Nombre,
                            Apellido = u.Apellido,
                            Dni = u.DNI,
                            UsuarioExternoId = u.UsuarioExternoId,
                            InscriptoCurso = (inscripcion.Curso != null && inscripcion.Curso.CursoId == CourseId),
                            CursoId = 
                            (inscripcion.Curso != null && inscripcion.Curso.CursoId == CourseId) 
                            ? inscripcion.Curso.CursoId 
                            : -1
                        };

    return await query.Where(ins => ins.CursoId == -1 || ins.CursoId == CourseId).ToListAsync();  
}
```

This line is checking if the user is enrolled in a course. If there's a row in `InscripcionRegistroCurso` for that user, it means that the user is enrolled to that course.

```
InscriptoCurso = (inscripcion.Curso != null && inscripcion.Curso.CursoId == CourseId)
```

Then `CursoId` is setting the id of the course, if it is the same id as the course Id in the razor page query param then it sets it, else it sets -1.

`UsuarioAgenteInscripto` is a class to gather the information about a user + a particular course enrollment.

What I'm trying to accomplish here

I have a razor page for displaying courses (cursos), each row contains a button (called enroll users) that triggers another razor page and renders all users in UsuariosExternos DbSet. (*see image attached*) I can enroll users to the course by marking the checkbox.

The thing is that I need to list ALL users in a table, but I need to make sure if there are users that are already enrolled in the course, a checkbox should be marked indicating this situation.

https://localhost/Inscripciones/Inscripcion?id=1

Id is the course Id.

[image: Example of user enrollment]

I'm doing a right join, to make sure all users are listed, the problem is that I'm getting repeated users, because one user can be enrolled in several courses. I need to filter this situation and show only Users enrolled in courses with the courseId equals to the current course *(the one in the page, with the course id in the query param.)* OR users enrolled in different courses (but only once, not every time the user is enrolled) If the user does not contain an enrollment, I'm setting -1 to `CursoId`
Each User can enroll in a particular course only once. *I mean a user can't be enrolled twice in the same course.*

For example, say I have users **John, Marty and Biff** and we are at the enrollment page for course xxxx with CourseId = 2.

- John has a enrollment in the current course and no other enrollments
- Marty does not have any enrollment.
- Biff has enrollments in 2 other courses

So my user list should contain the following

| Name / Nombre | CourseId / CursoId | isEnrolled / InscriptoCurso |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 2 | true |
| Marty | -1 | false |
| Biff | -1 | false |

But instead has the following

| Name / Nombre | CourseId / CursoId | isEnrolled / InscriptoCurso |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 2 | true |
| Marty | -1 | false |
| Biff | -1 | false |
| Biff | -1 | false |

I tried my best to explain the situation, let me know if i need to explain more.

Comment: Naturally, this is a many-to-many relationship. You wouldn't need the isEnrolled field or the negative number in the CourseId field. Create a junction table storing the PersonId and the CourseId. Then all you'll need to do is query that table to get the people enrolled.

Comment: mm I'm not sure, I have the following relation. From Usuario externo I can have 0 to N InscripcionRegistroCurso elements and each InscripcionRegistroCurso belongs to one and only one UsuarioExterno.

Comment: select s.StudentName, c.CourseName from dbo.StudentCourses sc join dbo.Students s on s.StudentId = sc.StudentId  join dbo.Courses c on c.CourseId = sc.CourseId where s.StudentId = @myId (I call that developer sql!!)